# How can you open an Australian bank account with a short-term visa?

Tags: australia, money

How and where can you open a bank account in Australia if you are on a short-term visa (up to six months)?

Comment: Do you have a “permanent” address in Australia (I.e. do you rent a flat or house)?

Comment: Not sure how reliable this information is, but according to https://www.internations.org/australia-expats/guide/banks-taxes if you wait until you are in the country to open your account and do so within six weeks of arriving in Australia, all you will require is your passport. You can forgo the 100 point check.

Answer (score 2):

All major Australian account offer migrant accounts.  Here's the process for CommBank, the largest one:

https://www.commbank.com.au/moving-to-australia/banking.html

The main hurdle is usually the "[100 points of ID](https://www.commbank.com.au/support.banking.id-check-documents.html)" requirement, which can be difficult to fulfill if you don't have proof of residence (lease etc).

Comment: That "100 points" link says all you need is a passport, foreign tax ID numbers and letter of enrollment.

Answer (score 2):

If you sign up for a [Wise](https://wise.com) account, you get [fully functional Aussie bank details](https://wise.com/us/borderless/aud-account) if you create an AUD balance within your account. It allows you to receive money and send money like a local. I’m not entirely sure if there’s a meaningful difference to a “real” account, but if all you want to do is send and receive money using local Aussie bank details, this will do just fine.